# Stock Mutation with Mysql

Tags: mysql, stock, mutation

I have mutation table that stores transactions:

| M_Date | Item_ID | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-02 | B-0001 | 4 |
| 2024-01-03 | B-0001 | 2 |
| 2024-01-03 | B-0001 | -1 |
| 2024-01-04 | B-0001 | -2 |
| 2024-01-03 | B-0002 | 5 |
| 2024-01-03 | B-0002 | -2 |
| 2024-01-04 | B-0002 | 1 |
| 2024-01-06 | B-0002 | -2 |

the scenario is; I select begin date and end date (for example I choose from 2024-01-01 to 2024-01-31)
to show data from mutation table like this :

| Item_ID | entry_date | b_balance | Mutation_In | Mutation_Out | e_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B-0001 | 2024-01-02 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 4 |
| B-0001 | 2024-01-03 | 4 | 2 | -1 | 5 |
| B-0001 | 2024-01-04 | 5 | 0 | -2 | 3 |
| B-0002 | 2024-01-03 | 0 | 5 | -2 | 3 |
| B-0002 | 2024-01-04 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| B-0002 | 2024-01-06 | 4 | 0 | -2 | 2 |

how to query in mysql to get the above result? any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```sql
select item_id, entry_date,
  b_balance, 
  pos as mutation_in,
  neg as mutation_out,
  b_balance + pos + neg as e_balance
from (
  select x.*,
    coalesce(sum(neg + pos) over (partition by item_id order by entry_date 
      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) as b_balance  
  from (
    select item_id, m_date as entry_date,
      sum(case when qty < 0 then qty else 0 end) as neg,
      sum(case when qty > 0 then qty else 0 end) as pos
    from t
    group by item_id, m_date
  ) x
) y
order by item_id, entry_date
```

Result:

```
 item_id  entry_date  b_balance  mutation_in  mutation_out  e_balance 
 -------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ------------- --------- 
 B-0001   2024-01-02  0          4            0             4         
 B-0001   2024-01-03  4          2            -1            5         
 B-0001   2024-01-04  5          0            -2            3         
 B-0002   2024-01-03  0          5            -2            3         
 B-0002   2024-01-04  3          1            0             4         
 B-0002   2024-01-06  4          0            -2            2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6CD2bv95) -- **with/without filtering**.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works great when I don't filter the date. the problem is when I filter the date, the b_balance is always 0. how can I get the b_balance that sum from previous date for every items in the beginning?

Comment: @Pramono I added the extra query in the fiddle, now with filtering. The balance does not start with zero in it. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6CD2bv95).

Comment: I tried your final solution and it works perfectly. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One option to do it could be like here:

```sql
--  S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table MUTATION (M_DATE DATE, ITEM_ID TEXT, QTY INT);
Insert Into MUTATION 
    VALUES  ('2024-01-02', 'B-0001', 4),
            ('2024-01-03', 'B-0001', 2),
            ('2024-01-03', 'B-0001', -1),
            ('2024-01-04', 'B-0001', -2),
            ('2024-01-03', 'B-0002', 5),
            ('2024-01-03', 'B-0002', -2),
            ('2024-01-04', 'B-0002', 1),
            ('2024-01-06', 'B-0002', -2);
```

```sql
--  S Q L :
SELECT m.ITEM_ID, m.M_DATE,
       Coalesce(Sum(m.MUTATION_QTY) 
                  Over(Partition By m.ITEM_ID Order By m.M_DATE
                    Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding), 0) "B_BALANCE",
       m.MUTATION_IN, m.MUTATION_OUT, 
       Coalesce(Sum(m.MUTATION_QTY) 
                  Over(Partition By m.ITEM_ID Order By m.M_DATE
                    Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding), 0) +
       m.MUTATION_QTY "E_BALANCE" 
FROM
    (Select ITEM_ID, M_DATE, 
            Sum(Case When QTY >= 0 Then QTY Else 0 END) "MUTATION_IN", 
            Sum(Case When QTY < 0 Then QTY Else 0 END)  "MUTATION_OUT",
            Sum(QTY) "MUTATION_QTY"
    From MUTATION
    Group By ITEM_ID, M_DATE) m;
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
ITEM_ID  M_DATE       B_BALANCE  MUTATION_IN    MUTATION_OUT    E_BALANCE
-------  -----------  ---------  -----------  --------------  -----------
B-0001   2024-01-02           0            4               0            4
B-0001   2024-01-03           4            2              -1            5
B-0001   2024-01-04           5            0              -2            3
B-0002   2024-01-03           0            5              -2            3
B-0002   2024-01-04           3            1               0            4
B-0002   2024-01-06           4            0              -2            2    */
```